# Trying to get rid of help text in Django results into error: a list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get rid via backend (not with CSS) of help text underneath the user field in a custom User UpdateView. This is my code:

```
class UpdateCustomUser(UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
    template_name = 'auth/user_update_form.html'
    context_object_name = 'current_user'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateCustomUser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for fieldname in ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
```

Unfortunately, this is the error I get:

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I do not understand why this is happening, considering the code I use to get rid of the help text in the user creation form works perfectly and does not throw any error:

```
class CustomUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='Required')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(CustomUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        # user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            user.save()
            return user

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for fieldname in ['username', 'password1', 'password2']:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing forms and views, which are not at all the same. That works on CustomUserForm, which is a form; it will not work on UpdateCustomUser, which is a view.

The solution would be to define a form for UpdateCustomUser and put the code there.

```
class CustomUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for fieldname in ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None

class UpdateCustomUser(UpdateView):
    form_class = CustomUserForm
    template_name = 'auth/user_update_form.html'
    context_object_name = 'current_user'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I  still am confusing basic concepts like forms and views...Btw, still the help text is displayed with your solution. Should I call the __init__ method inside the view in order to not display the help text?

Comment: Ok it works now, I had to set form_class as attribute instead of form :)